# How to delete the oldest file over FTP using CURL?

Tags: ftp, curl

I am trying to write a script that will use CURL to FTP to a folder on a file server, then count the files in that folder. If there are more than 5 files, delete the oldest one.

I know how to delete files over FTP with CURL, however the counting and getting oldest file name is where I am lost.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this through curl. You would need to run `curl -l` to list the directory contents, count the matches, sort by date, and issue remote `rm` commands with `curl -Q`.

If your system supports [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) (most do), I recommend to mount the remote directory as a filesystem. This approach lets you split your problem into two separate tasks: access the remote files by mounting them, and work on them as you would on local files. You can use [curlftpfs](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/) for the remote mounting.

```
mkdir ftp.example.com
curlftpfs ftp.example.com ftp.example.com
cp -p /path/to/local/file ftp.example.com/remote/dir/
```

Now, to find the oldest files in a directory, the easiest way is to use zsh and its [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers). Working in the directory `ftp.example.com/remote/dir/`:

```
files=(*(mm))                # Om = sort by date, youngest first
if ((${#files} > 5)); then
  rm $files[-1]              # remove the last file
  # rm $files[6,-1]          # remove all but the 5 youngest files
fi
```

Comment: Hmm I am not sure if the mounting option would work as it is a GoDaddy basic web hosting package with FTP that I am sending files to.

Comment: @Ryan Mounting only relies on having FTP access. FUSE is only a problem if your *local* machine is restricted.