# How to loop through each file in FTP directory using a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, ftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete the oldest file over FTP using CURL?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38365/how-to-delete-the-oldest-file-over-ftp-using-curl)

I need to connect to a remote server using a bash script and then delete all files within the directory that are older than 7 days. I'm trying to do this with a for loop within the FTP remote server and I get an error.

```
#!/bin/sh

HOST='www.ftpserver.com'
USER='username'
PASSWD='password'

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
user ${USER} ${PASSWD}


for i in {ls}
do
 echo "$i"
done

quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

The error I get is

```
We only support non-print format, sorry.
?Invalid command
?Invalid command
```

Any pointers will help

Comment: Not sure if it's "The Right Way", but you could use [FTPFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPFS) and any Bash script you like.

Comment: lftp can run in batch mode, as in `lftp -u username,password ftp://server -e "ls"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either rewrite your script in: [Perl](http://aplawrence.com/Unixart/perlnetftp.html), PHP or Python, as they all offer API's for FTP, else have a look at using [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect). There are several tutorials around.

Answer (score 2):

The [FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) protocol has a very limited set of commands. You cannot use shell scripting with a ftp connection. If you want to do that, use telnet or ssh.